# Hide an item in the tabBar?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

i currently have a number of viewControllers that have a relationship with my tabBarController through Storyboard.  Given certain setting, i would like to programatically make a certain viewController hidden or visible.  I can hide the whole tabBar, but thats not what i'm after. I have been playing in Xcode and scouring interwebs, but can't find a solution. something along the lines of below that doesn't work me!

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Used similar code to fix the problem.

```
NSMutableArray *newTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[newTabs removeObjectAtIndex: 3];
[newTabs removeObjectAtIndex: 2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newTabs];
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. This removes it rather than hiding it. What if the program needs to show it again?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can do it in one line:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 1)
```

Assume that `1` is the index of the item you want to remove.

Comment: Unfortunately this changes the indices of the other tabs which can break functionality. It would really be nice to just be able to hide a tab.

Answer (score -1):

To change a `UITabBar`, set its `items` property to something new

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
NSMutableArray *newTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBar.items];
[newTabs removeObjectAtIndex: 2];
tabBar.items = newTabs;
```

Comment: Doesn't work:  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'